# Rails 4: validate a model only on specific action

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to validate an `email` object only when I'm actually sending the email and not everytime I'm updating it:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Runs on every update/save method
  validates :body, presence: true

  def send_email
    # Only run when this method is called
    if body.blank?
      errors.add :body, "can't be blank"
      raise ActiveRecord::InvalidRecord.new(self)
    end

    update_column(:sent_at, Time.zone.now)
    EmailMailer.new_email(self).deliver
  end
end
```

Currently, this code will validate the `body` on every update, but I only want to validate when the `send_email` method is called. The reasoning is I want to allow users to save the email without actually sending, and this validation forces them to have a value.

I can manually check the validation in  my method, but was wondering if there was a "cleaner" approach to this, something like:

```
validates :body, presence: true, action: :send_email # does not work, but what I want
```

**Update 2015-08-13 15:30**

I have some semi-working code, but would prefer a cleaner solution than what I have:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  # remove validate methods

  def send_email
    errors.add :body, "can't be blank" if body.blank?

    # My application has some higher level controller code that handles exceptions.
    raise ActiveRecord::InvalidRecord.new(self) if errors.any?

    # code execution should be stopped by exception...
  end
end
```

Comment: hope this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914257/rails-activerecord-validation-on-specific-controller-and-action

Comment: Check out Conditional Validation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

Comment: @Athar: thanks for the link, I reviewed that question before posting mine. That question dealt with the creation cycle and conditionally firing the validations on a specific event that triggered an update.  In my case, I want a non-persistance method to fire off the validations instead.

Comment: @FanJin: the API guides deal with conditional validations during the persistence cycle (ie, do I persist this attribute given these conditions, etc...).  What I'm trying to accomplish is to fire the validation methods outside of the persistence cycle.

Comment: so if you add the `attr_accessor :validate_body`. and in `send_email` set the `validate_body= true` now in the validation do this `validates :body, presence: true if :validate_body?` now add a method which `def validate_body?` in which check the `self.validate_body ==  true`. the validation will run at the time of send_email method the attr_accessor basically behave like a flag for validation. will this work for your case.?

Comment: let me know if things are messy i will post as answer. not posting actually as if i dont know it meets your requirement. Secondly why are you raising exception using `raise` do you want to make it crash or do you want to not update `sent_at` if body is blank?

Comment: @Athar: I'm using `raise` because I'm building an API and I have some handlers higher up in the controller code that handles the exception and returns a nice JSON response to the requester.  You are correct as well that I do not want the `sent_at` to update if the validation fails.

Comment: @Athar: after reviewing your comment/answer, I think doing `errors.add :base, :attr` is cleaner than my original idea of forcing `validates :attr` to do what it wasn't intended to do.

Comment: Yes. Your updated code is much cleaner and it will work good. (y)